# concern on solving Fundamental Theorem of Calculus 2

Tags: calculus, integration

> Given that
>   $$
> \int_0^\pi [f(x)+f''(x)]\sin x\,dx = 2
> $$
>   and $f(\pi)=1$, find $f(0)$.

I know I have to use the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the second theorem. I was suggested to use integration by parts, but I am not sure of my answer. I got $f(0)=2$, which I'm kinda skeptical of.

With integration by parts, the integral of $\sin(x)f(x)$ is $0$, and the final equation was $f'(x)\sin(x)-f(x)\cos(x)=2$. So, using $x=0$, it means you get $f(0)=2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You are not sure of what? Have you tried to integrate by parts, or are you waiting for some bored retired mathematician to do your homework for you?

Comment: thanks, @JoséCarlosSantos I appreciate that feedback. Will do so next time.

Comment: I explained the working in my comments, posting my solution would mean 2 more pict links. so, I just need feed back if I answer is right. I feel it was blind working

Answer (score 1):

We can split the integral:
$$
\int f(x)\sin x\,dx=-f(x)\cos x+\int f'(x)\cos x\,dx
$$
and
$$
\int f''(x)\sin x\,dx=f'(x)\sin x-\int f'(x)\cos x\,dx
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int [f(x)+f''(x)]\sin x\,dx=-f(x)\cos x+f'(x)\sin x+c
$$
which you can also verify by direct differentiation.

Now use the FTC and compute the integral from $0$ to $\pi$.